# **UPDATED** Error in method in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, associations, erb

I need a way to determine is a User has a Project.

My User model has a `has_one :project` declaration

and the Project model as a `belongs_to :User` declaration.

I want to set up a toggle state in my `app/views/users/show.html.erb` file using this logic...

```
<div id="snapshot">
    <h2>Project Snapshot</h2>
    <% if has_project? %>
        <% render 'projects/project_overview' %>
    <% else %>
        <% render 'projects/no_project' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The code for the ProjectsHelper method is...

```
<% def has_project %>
  <% current_user.project(params[:user_id]) %>
<% end %>
```

I need to know why this isn't rendering either option?  The view displays without error.

**Question has been updated from original.**

Comment: your `render` lines need to have an equals sign in front in order to actually be shown `<%= render 'projects/project_overview' %>`

Comment: Yup.  Thanks.  Noob error... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the equals sign in the statement.

Your code has:

```
<%= if has_project? %>
```

Should be:

```
<% if has_project? %>
```

#### Edit

Try changing your `<% if has_project? %>` to `<% if current_user.project %>` (because all it seems you want to do is query whether the current user has an associated project or not) and remove the helper method.  See [the Rails API entry on ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to find out what methods are provided when you create an association.

Comment: That resolved the syntaxerror, but now the code doesn't display either render option.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code for the method, found in `ProjectsHelper` is...

`def has_project?`
  `user = current_user.project(params[:user_id])`
`end`

Comment: Can you update your question with the code in the `has_project?` method?  Or, did you mean to write something like `<% if @user.project %>`?